# No config DB/storage for PHP

Tags: php, database, storage

For many small applications I need some form of storage and querying, but I'm getting tired of having to create a database and setting up table structures as I usually do with MySQL. I'd rather have a PHP framework / class that would simply write a db-like format through disk IO, no user/pass for 'db' access or database/table configurations.

Performance is not an issue as these apps will hardly be used. Data integrity however would be appreciated.

Is there anything like this available?

Comment: What are you trying to do? i didnt get it

Comment: Looking for a way to save/load stuff that usually goes into a db, but without the hassle of configuring a db, i.e. storing and loading users (id/name/email).

Comment: nodb? https://code.google.com/p/nodb-php-database/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[SQLite](http://www.sqlite.org) could be a good middle ground. You'll still need to set up tables, but this can all be kept in very trivial, self-contained code using [SQLite's `PRAGMA user_version`](http://www.sqlite.org/pragma.html#pragma_schema_version):

```
$pdo     = new PDO('sqlite:/path/to/my/database.sq3');
$version = $pdo->query('PRAGMA user_version')->fetchColumn();

switch ($version) {
    case 0:
        $pdo->execute('CREATE ...');
        ...
        $pdo->execute('PRAGMA user_version = 1');
    ...
}
```

This is essentially a self-contained migration system you can easily run every time you connect to the database, which ensures the database schema is set up as needed, which is a minimum of hassle you should accept anyway. It still gives you most of the features of a full SQL server, in a self contained single file.

Comment: Played around for a couple of hours, this is pretty cool and properly supported. No more phpmyadmin :)